# Convergence with Meizu Pro 5 over USB C?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screen, usb-c

I'm interested in the answer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751923/questions-about-meizu-pro-5-ubuntu-edition-specs) but nobody has answered to it:

> [Meizu] says [the Meizu Pro 5] will not support video and audio over USB C. Is this a software or hardware related issue?

Will it be possible to plug a USB C to HDMI adapter in order to have Convergence?

Answer (score 0):

apparently audio video isn't supported over USB C on Meizu Pro 5. But you can do convergence using [wireless display](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DisplayCasting)